# Multiple replace para un arreglo de palabras

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, filtro, str-replace

Estoy creando un filtrado de palabras en `Javascript`, usando el método `replace` para cambiar cada palabra que tengo dentro de un arreglo, tengo lo siguiente

```
function filter(e){
var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var color = ["rojo","verde","azul"];

      for(i=0;i<=color.length-1;i++)
      {
       var quitar = color[i];
       text = text.replace(quitar,"*");
      }
}
```

De momento cuando se escriba dentro del `input` este funcionara y remplazara en caso de haber escrito alguno de los colores declarados dentro del arreglo por el `*`.

Ahora lo que busco hacer es que el método `replace` considere cada palabra como global (**/verde/g**) para que en caso de que se escriba mas de 2 veces un color remplace todas y no solo la primera que encuentre.

Como estoy pasando una variable para el primer parámetro de `replace`, no se de que manera hacer que interprete que sea una variable o cada palabra con el **/g** de global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> lo que busco hacer es que el metodo replace considere cada palabra como global (/verde/g) para que en caso de que se escriba mas de 2 veces un color remplace todas y no solo la primera que encuentre.

### Solución:

Puedes usar [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) para crear una expresión regular que encuentre la palabra e indicar el `flag` `g` para que reemplace todas las ocurrencias de la misma.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function filter(e) {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var color = ["rojo", "verde", "azul"];

  for (i = 0; i <= color.length - 1; i++) {
    var quitar = color[i];
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(quitar, 'g'), "*");
  }
  
  console.log(text);
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', filter);
```

```html
<input id="input" value="violeta rojo verde azul violeta rojo verde azul" />
<button id="button">Filtrar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No se puede hacer de esa manera, tenes que hacerlo usando RegEx.

Usando RegEx

```
function replaceAll(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Otra alternativa usando Split y Join

```
function replaceAll(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Comment: Te estaría faltando explicar como ejecutar dichas funciones